# jquery script not closing the «openedElem» when a child of the «openElem» is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have this jquery script not closing the «openedElem» when a child of the «openedElem» is clicked? My goal is to insert an ajax form into one of the sliding panel. Any suggestions?

```
<code>
$(function(){
    var openedElem = null;
    $("a.click").click(function(){
        var nextElem = $(this).next();

        if (openedElem !== null) {
            if (openedElem.attr("id") === nextElem.attr("id")) {
                return false;
            }
            openedElem.slideUp();
        }

        openedElem = nextElem.slideDown();
    });
});
</code>
```

Comment: It does not look like this code would be executed if a descendant of `openedElem` is clicked. `openedElem` seems to be a **sibling** of the element the event handler is bound to, so what is the problem? *edit:* What is the `openElement`?

Answer (score 0):

If the child of the `<a>` element is causing the event handler to trigger, stop the bubbling up on those children.

With all the HTML posted, it's going to be a wild guess, but maybe this will work:

```
$("a.click").children().on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Or `$("a.click").children().click(false)`, though just checking whether `event.target === this` inside the handler is probably better.

Comment: @FelixKling - Was actually going for the last one, as I use that myself from time to time, but all I see in the posted code is a bunch of variables, so went with the safe option, as it's hard to see what's what in that code, at least for me ?